# How do i upload my react js to wordpress. I want it to show in the wordpress dashboard as a widget

Tags: php, reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

How do I upload my reactjs file to WordPress. I want it to show in the WordPress dashboard as a widget

I have created a dashboard widget and I used react Js and I want it to show as a WordPress dashboard.

I really don't know how to go about it

[image: an image of the widget]

Answer (score -1):

To use React in a WordPress plugin, you'll need to follow these steps:

1. Set up your development environment: Install Node.js and a code editor, such as Visual Studio Code. Create a new directory for your plugin and navigate to it in your terminal or command prompt.
2. Install the required dependencies: Run the following command in your terminal to install the necessary dependencies:

```
npm install --save-dev react react-dom @babel/core @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react babel-loader webpack webpack-cli
```

3. Create a React component: Create a new file called "MyComponent.jsx" in your plugin directory and add your React component code. For example:

```
import React from 'react';
    
function MyComponent() {
   return <h1>Hello, world!</h1>;
}
  
export default MyComponent;
```

4. Create a JavaScript file: Create a new file called "index.js" in your plugin directory and add the following code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import MyComponent from './MyComponent.jsx';

function renderMyComponent() {
  ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.getElementById('my-plugin-container'));
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', renderMyComponent);
```

This code imports the React and ReactDOM libraries, as well as your "MyComponent" file. It then renders your component inside a container element on the page.

5. Create a webpack configuration file: Create a new file called "webpack.config.js" in your plugin directory and add the following code:
   css

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'my-plugin.js',
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

This code configures webpack to bundle your JavaScript files and transpile them using Babel.

6. Build the plugin: Run the following command in your terminal to build your plugin:

```
npx webpack --mode production
```

This command bundles your JavaScript files and creates a new file called "my-plugin.js" in the "dist" directory of your plugin.

7. Enqueue the script: In your plugin code, use the wp_enqueue_script function to enqueue your script. Here's an example:

```
function my_plugin_enqueue_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script(
    'my-plugin-js',
    plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'dist/my-plugin.js',
    array( 'jquery' ),
    '1.0.0',
    true
  );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_plugin_enqueue_scripts' );
```

This code enqueues your "my-plugin.js" file on the frontend of your site.

That's it! With these steps, you can use React in your WordPress plugin.